# How to use JPA findBy query on column mapped by @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to use jpa query to find a record from column which has @OneToMany relationship?

Post.class

```
public class Post {
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...
  ...
  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "comment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<Comment> comments;

}
```

Comment.class

```
public class Comment {
  ...
  ...

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "comment", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Post post;
}
```

Is there any way to query on `PostRepository` and find the `Post` using commentId ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `Comment` has the property `String id` you could do this as follows:

```java
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, String> {
    List<Post> findByCommentsId(String id);
}
```

You can read more about this on:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-keywords-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

To find by commentId you just have to create a function in your repository interface :

```
List<Comment> findByPost(Post post);
```

Then when you query just add :

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setId(yourId);
repository.findByPost(post);
```

Comment: Hibernate will complain for this as the post object is in transient state.