# Hibernate/JPA/Spring boot - object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've seen there is a couple of answers for this already, however, I can't seem to get it right.

This is the error I get:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

This is the Item table (simplified it as much as possible)
And yes, it has 2 references to it self

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "item",
)
public class Item {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "desc"
    private String description;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_2")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsExclude
    private Item id_2;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_3")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsExclude
    private Item id_3;
}
```

And the dto

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Schema(name="item")
public class ItemDto implements Serializable {

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Long version;
    private ItemDto id_2;
    private ItemDto id_3;
}
```

And then I have the category tables, which has a reference to an Item.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy ...)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsExclude
    private Item item;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;
}
```

and the category dto

```
@Data
@Schema(name="Category")
public class CategoryDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String description;
    @NotNull
    private ItemDto item;
    private Long version;
}
```

In the category repository I have this:

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

    List<Category> findByItem(Item item);
}
```

In the service I try to find the categories that has this item

```
    protected ResponseEntity<List<CategoryDto>> filterCategoriesByItem(String name) {

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName(name);

        // Here is where I get the transient / save flush error
        List<CategoryDto> list = categoryRepository.findByItem(item)
             .stream()
             .map(mapper::toDto)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        ...
        ...
    }
```

But when I execute the last line `findByItem(item)`
I get this:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

I saw some posts about using `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` and I tried all sorts of combinations, to no avail and with same error.

If anyone has some spare time this rainy Saturday, I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a entity class object, hibernate takes control of it by tracking the state of the object i.e. transient, persisted or detached.

What you can do is to update your repository method to accept name as a string parameter and perform the query in repo method.

Or see this solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400101/6572971